# first Console.ReadLine() returns immediately

Tags: c#, console-application

I am writing a really silly program.

I have no idea why the following code won't work:

```
static void Main(string[] args){
        <Some silly code>
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose the lab you are working on:");
        int choose = Console.Read();
        <Some more silly code, including 1 Console.writeLine() call >

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the DB server location");
        string DBServer = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the DB name");
        string DBName = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

When I run the program, it never waits for the first ReadLine statement

```
string DBServer = Console.ReadLine();
```

It prints the two rows immediately

```
Enter the DB server location  
Enter the DB name
```

And then reads the second ReadLine `string DBName = Console.ReadLine();`

When I check the input form user, it indeed reads the second one well, but the first string comes out empty.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using `Console.Read` which will reach a character but will leave the carriage-return after it alone. Which will then be picked up by `ReadLine`.

Input is a stream. When you are entering a single character and then hit return there are 2–3 characters in the stream (depending on the system): The character you entered and the line break. `Read` just gives you the next character in the stream, while `ReadLine` will read everything up to the next line break. Again, from the stream. So your `Read` fetches a character and ReadLine already finds the next line break and thus continues happily.

You can either insert a dummy `ReadLine`, or use `ReadKey` which will just read a key and won't need a return before your program sees the input, or use `ReadLine` for the single-character input as well.